# Nagios define service for nrpe command in Windows environment

Tags: configuration, nagios, nrpe, nsclient++

I'm trying to configure Nagios to monitor our network which is all Windows based. I'm totally new to it, so please forgive my naiveness. Fact is: I'm banging my head over a task.

What I want to achieve is having Nagios tell me whether a remote service/process is running or not.
I have NSClilent++ installed and working on a client machine. In fact, if I execute the following code from command line in the Nagios server it works:

```
check_nrpe -H [ip_of_NSClient++] -c check_service -a 'service=[service_name]' "critical=state = 'stopped'"
```

**My question is: how can I define aservice in the [*host*].cfg file to invoke the command above?**

Right now I have this defined in my commands.cfg file:

```
   define command {
   $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -a $ARG1$
    }
```

Which works to invoke simple services like [check_cpu] or [check_disk] but no more than that.

All the attempts I've done so far always led to(I think) erratic error messages, like:

- (No output on stdout) stderr: Could not resolve hostname $: Name or service not known.
  or
- CHECK_NRPE: Invalid packet type received from server.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.
In the end, I downgraded the NSClient to a previous version and it worked.
Now my cfg file looks like:
`define service{
[...]
check_command  check_nrpe!alias_service!"[service desc] CRITICAL = OK"
}`

and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a specific check buit in nrpe client for Windows service

It is:

```
check_command        check_windows_service!"<display name of the service>"
```

You have to enter the **display** name of the service as it appears in windows service manager.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the Old Skool

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service
        host_name                       YourServer
        service_description             YourService
        check_command                   check_nt!SERVICESTATE!-d SHOWALL -l YourService
        }
```

That said, I hauled out my check_nrpe definitions and found:

```
# this command runs a program $ARG1$ with arguments $ARG2$
define command {
        command_name    check_nrpe
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -a $ARG2$
}

# this command runs a program $ARG1$ with no arguments
define command {
        command_name    check_nrpe_1arg
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
}
```

I honestly don't remember if I created the second one or not (I probably did, though).  However, yours has ARG1 specified twice, while you have two arguments:

```
  define command {
   $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -a $ARG1$
    }
```

It should probably be

```
  define command {
   $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -a $ARG2$
    }
```